# Using split on each element of a vector

Tags: clojure

Basically, I have used slurp to get the contents of a file that is supposed to be a database. I've split the data already once and have a vector that contains all the information correctly. Now I would like to split each element in the vector again. This would give me a vector of vectors. My problem is I can't seem to find the right way to iterate through the vector and make my changes. The changes either don't work or are not stored in the vector.

Using doseq:

```
(doseq [x tempVector]
        (clojure.string/split x #"|")
    )
```

If I add a print statement in the loop it prints everything spaced out with no changes.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `str/split` function returns a new vector of strings, which you need to save.  Right now it is being generated and then discarded.  You need something like this:

```
(ns xyz
  (:require
    [clojure.string :as str]))

(def x "hello there to you")
(def y (str/split x #" "))  ; save result in `y`
(def z (str/split x #"e"))  ; save result in `z`

y => ["hello" "there" "to" "you"]
z => ["h" "llo th" "r" " to you"]
```

You can read clojure basics online here:  https://www.braveclojure.com .
I recommend buying the book as it has more stuff than the online version.

If you have several strings in a vector, you can use the `map` function to split each of them in turn:

```
(def my-strings
  ["hello is there anybody in there?"
   "just nod if you can hear me"
   "is there anyone at home?"])

(def my-strings-split
  (mapv #(str/split % #" ") my-strings))

my-strings-split   => 
  [["hello" "is" "there" "anybody" "in" "there?"]
   ["just" "nod" "if" "you" "can" "hear" "me"]
   ["is" "there" "anyone" "at" "home?"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

To restructure your slurped lines of text into a collection of vectors of words you could do something like:

```
(use '[clojure.string :as str :only [split]])

(defn file-as-words [filename re]
  (let [lines      (line-seq (clojure.java.io/reader filename))
        line-words (vec (mapv #(str/split %1 re) lines))]
    line-words))
```

Here we define a function which first uses `line-seq` to slurp the file in and break it into a collection of lines, then we map an anonymous function which invokes clojure.string/split on each line in the initial collection, breaking each line up into a collection of words delimited by the passed-in regular expression. The collection of vectors-of-words is returned.

For example, let's say we have a file named `/usr/data/test.dat` which contains

```
Alice,Eating,001
Kitty,Football,006
May,Football,004
```

If we invoke `file-as-words` by using

```
(file-as-words "/usr/data/test.dat" #",")
```

you get back

```
[["Alice" "Eating" "001"] ["Kitty" "Football" "006"] ["May" "Football" "004"]]
```